# Play! framework 2.0: Validate field in forms using other fields

Tags: scala, playframework, validation

In the play! framework, using scala,say that i have a form such as follows:

```
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.validation.Constraints._

case class User(someStringField: String, someIntField: Int)

val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "someStringField" -> text,
    "someIntField" -> number verifying(x => SomeMethodThatReceivesAnIntAndReturnsABoolean(x))
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
```

)

where `SomeMethodThatReceivesAnIntAndReturnsABoolean` is a method that performs some logic on the int to validate it.

However, i would like to be able to consider the value of the `someStringField` when validating the `someIntField`, is there a way to achieve this in play framework's forms? I know that i can do something like:

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "someStringField" -> text,
    "someIntField" -> number 
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
.verifying(x => SomeFunctionThatReceivesAnUserAndReturnsABoolean(x))
```

and then i would have the entire user instance available passed to the validation function.  The problem with that approach is that the resulting error would be associated with the entire form instead of being associated with the `someIntField` field.

Is there a way to get both things, validate a field using another field and maintain the error associated to the specific field i wish to validate, instead of the entire form?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same requirements with adding validation to fields depending on the value of other fields. I´m not sure how this is done in idiomatic PLAY 2.2.1 but I came up with the following solution. In this usage I´m degrading the builtin "mapping" into a simple type converter and apply my "advanced inter field" validation in the "validateForm" method. The mapping:

```
val userForm = Form(
mapping(
  "id" -> optional(longNumber),
  "surename" -> text,
  "forename" -> text,
  "username" -> text,
  "age" -> number
)(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)

private def validateForm(form:Form[User]) = {
  if(form("username").value.get == "tom" || form("age").value.get == "38") {
    form
      .withError("forename", "tom - forename error")
      .withError("surename", "tom - surename error")
  }
  else
    form
}

def update = Action { implicit request =>
  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold({
    formWithErrors => BadRequest(users.edit(validateForm(formWithErrors)))
  }, { user => 
    val theForm = validateForm(userForm.fill(user))
    if(theForm.hasErrors) {
      BadRequest(users.edit(theForm))
    } else {
      Users.update(user)
      Redirect(routes.UsersController.index).flashing("notice" -> s"${user.forename} updated!")
    }
  }) 
}
```

Even though it works I´m urgently searching for a more idiomatic version...

**EDIT:** Use a custom play.api.data.format.Formatter in idiomatic play, more on http://workwithplay.com/blog/2013/07/10/advanced-forms-techniques/ - this lets you programmatically add errors to a form. My Formatter looks like this:

```
val usernameFormatter = new Formatter[String] {

override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], String] = {
  // "data" lets you access all form data values
  val age = data.get("age").get
  val username = data.get("username").get
  if(age == "66") {
    Left(List(FormError("username", "invalid"), FormError("forename", "invalid")))
  } else {
    Right(username)
  }
}

override def unbind(key: String, value: String): Map[String, String] = {
  Map(key -> value)
}
}
}
```

Registered in the form mapping like this:

```
mapping(
[...]
  "username" -> of(usernameFormatter),
[....]
```

Comment: Still doesn't feel idiomatic enough for me...  It's been a long time I did this question, and since then, I've been working on my own validation framework for scala https://github.com/NovaMage/SValidator.    The implementation is almost finished but it's not well documented yet.  It has a full suit of unit tests though.  Once I finish the documentation about how to use it and how to integrate it with play, I'll post it here as an answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you're looking for is [`play.api.data.validation.Constraint`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.validation.Constraint).

Say you have a `RegisterForm` with a list of predefined `cities` and an `otherCity` field and you need either the `cities` or `otherCity` to be supplied, i.e., `otherCity` should be validated if `cities` is not provided:

```
case class RegisterForm(
  email: String,
  password: String,
  cities: Option[List[String]],
  otherCity: Option[String]
)
```

You can write a custom [Constraint](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomValidations) around this:

```
val citiesCheckConstraint: Constraint[RegisterForm] = Constraint("constraints.citiescheck")({
  registerForm =>
    // you have access to all the fields in the form here and can
    // write complex logic here
    if (registerForm.cities.isDefined || registerForm.otherCity.isDefined) {
      Valid
    } else {
      Invalid(Seq(ValidationError("City must be selected")))
    }
})
```

And your form definition becomes:

```
val registerForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(emailCheckConstraint),
    "password" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(passwordCheckConstraint),
    "cities" -> optional(list(text)),
    "other_city" -> optional(text)
  )(RegisterForm.apply)(RegisterForm.unapply).verifying(citiesCheckConstraint)
)
```

In this example `emailCheckConstraint` and `passwordCheckConstraint` are additional custom constraints that I defined similar to `citiesCheckConstraint`. This works in Play 2.2.x.

**UPDATE:**
Works on Play 2.3.8 as well.

Comment: how do you set the error for particular field then?

Answer (score 3):

if you don't mind having a prefix for you params you can group the related params:

```
val aForm = Form(
mapping(
  "prefix" -> tuple(
    "someStringField" -> text,
    "someIntField" -> number
  ) verifying (tup => your verification)
)(tup => User.apply(tup._1, tup._2)(User.unapply...)
```

I use something similar just without the surrounding mapping.
You will have to adjust the apply/unapply a little and pass the arguments manually for it to compile.

The error will be registered to the "prefix" group.

I also find it weird that you cannot register errors on any field you'd like using FormError when verifying the form...

Comment: This approach doesn't work, because the error will be associated to the "prefix" field.  I wanted it to be associated to the "someIntField".  While I could accept using "prefix" instead, the problem will come back again if I need another field to be validated taking into account the "someStringField" value.  Both errors would end up being associated to the "prefix" field.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Tom Myer, Here what I used

```
class MatchConstraint[A](val targetField:String, val map:(String, Map[String, String]) => A, val unmap:A => String) extends Formatter[A] {
  override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], A] = {
    val first = data.getOrElse(key, "")
    val second = data.getOrElse(targetField, "")
    if (first == "" || !first.equals(second)) {
      Left(List(FormError(key, "Not Match!")))
    }
    else {
      Right(map(key, data))
    }
  }

  override def unbind(key: String, value: A): Map[String, String] = Map(key -> unmap(value))
}
```

And here what's my form look like

```
val registerForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> email.verifying(minLength(6)),
    "password" -> text(minLength = 6),
    "passwordConfirmation" -> of(new MatchConstraint[String]("password", (key, data) => data.getOrElse(key, ""), str => str))
  )(RegisterData.apply)(RegisterData.unapply)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that they map the scala-code to JSR-Validation. There it's definitely not possible. There are some arguments to do this. Mainly that a validation should be simple and not make complex logic. How ever I still miss this too. OVal from play1 was better for me.

Comment: That's strange.  I thought that things such as requiring a certain field when another field was not empty was common thing, and not considered complex logic. Thus it's strange no one has bumped into this before, especially the play! framework creators themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation: 
[Playframework Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms)

You can see the following code: 
`val userFormConstraintsAdHoc = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "age" -> number
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply) verifying("Failed form constraints!", fields => fields match {
    case userData => validate(userData.name, userData.age).isDefined
  })
)`

Mainly just verify after the unapply and you have all the fields mapped, so you can make a more complete validation.