# play framework form validation in scala

Tags: scala, playframework

Working of play framework form validation in scala
follows my Signup object, it gives me an error at the line "mapping(": "missing 
arguments for method mapping in object Forms; follow this method with `_' if you want to
treat it as a partially applied function"

```
case class UserRegistration(username: String, password1: String, password2: String)

val loginForm = Form(
 mapping(
   "username" -> email,
   "password1" -> text,
   "password2" -> text
 )
 (UserRegistration.apply)(UserRegistration.unapply)
 verifying ("Passwords must match",  => f.password1 == f.password2)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case class UserRegistration(username: String, password1: String, password2: String)

val loginForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> email,
    "password1" -> text,
    "password2" -> text
  )
  (UserRegistration.apply)(UserRegistration.unapply)
  verifying ("Passwords must match", f => f.password1 == f.password2)
)
```

your missing the `("Passwords must match", f => f.password1 == f.password2)`

Answer (score 2):

Using verifying on the entire "form backing object" doesn´t let you add errors to individual fields in the form. If you want to do that see [Play! framework 2.0: Validate field in forms using other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100698/play-framework-2-0-validate-field-in-forms-using-other-fields/19877822#19877822)