# type mismatch on signup form with password confirmation

Tags: scala, playframework

i want to make signup form with password confirmation and copy this sample
https://github.com/namin/play-js-validation

but type mismatch occured

scala 2.11 
play 2.5

```
object SignUpForm {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> nonEmptyText,
      // "password" -> nonEmptyText
      "password" ->
            tuple(
                "main" -> nonEmptyText,
                "confirm" -> nonEmptyText
            ).verifying("Passwords don't match",passwords  => passwords._1 == passwords._2)
    )(Data1.apply)(Data1.unapply)
  )

    // The mapping signature doesn't match the User case class signature,
    // so we have to define custom binding/unbinding functions
    {
      // Binding: Create a User from the mapping result (ignore the second password and the accept field)
      (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
    } 

  case class Data1(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password1: String,
    password2: String
)

  case class Data2(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
)

}
```

> type mismatch;
>   found   : (String, String, String, String, String) => forms.SignUpForm.Data1
>   required: (String, String, String, (String, String)) => ?

```
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:25: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (String, String, String, String, String) => forms.SignUpForm.Data1
[error]  required: (String, String, String, (String, String)) => ?
[error]     )(Data1.apply)(Data1.unapply)
[error]             ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:25: missing argument list for method unapply in object Data1
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `unapply _` or `unapply(_)` instead of `unapply`.
[error]     )(Data1.apply)(Data1.unapply)
[error]                          ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:32: missing parameter type
[error]     (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
[error]      ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:32: missing parameter type
[error]     (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
[error]                 ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:32: missing parameter type
[error]     (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
[error]                           ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:32: missing parameter type
[error]     (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
[error]                                  ^
[error] /root/play-silhouette-seed/app/forms/SignUpForm.scala:32: missing parameter type
[error]     (firstName, lastName, email, passwords, _) => Data2(firstName, lastName, email, passwords._1)
[error]                                             ^
[error] 7 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application -
```

maybe case class Data1 should be modified but brace () could not be nested.for example,

```
  case class Data1(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    (password1: String,
    password2: String)
  )
```

occured error

> 5/24(after 2 hours)
>   rewrote but occured unexpected exception. don't know where to insert .verifying()

[model]

```
  case class Data(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: forms.SignUpForm.PassData
  )

  case class PassData(
    main: String,
    confirm: String
  )
```

[signupform]

```
  val form = Form[Data](
    mapping(
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> nonEmptyText,
      // "password" -> nonEmptyText
      "password" -> mapping(
        "main" -> nonEmptyText,
        "confirm" -> nonEmptyText
      )(PassData.apply)(PassData.unapply)
 // following .verifying is not appropriate
 .verifying("Passwords don't match",password  => password.main == password.confirm)
//(PassData.apply)(PassData.unapply)
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
   )
```

> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, org.quartz.SchedulerException: Scheduler with name 'QuartzScheduler~application' already exists.
  at jobs.Scheduler.<init>(Scheduler.scala:18)
  at modules.JobModule.bind(JobModule.scala:10) (via modules: 
com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> modules.JobModule)
  while locating jobs.Scheduler
```

> 5/24 (after 4 hours)
>   found this question and solved.
>   [play framework form validation in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539923/play-framework-form-validation-in-scala)

```
  val form = Form[Data](
    mapping(
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> nonEmptyText,
      "main" -> nonEmptyText,
      "confirm" -> nonEmptyText 
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
 verifying("Passwords don't match", password  => password.main == password.confirm)
  )

  case class Data(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    main: String,
    confirm: String
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using nested forms https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#nested-values

You can create a field for passwords and nest two fields inside password field.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i tried it but don' know how to confirm password

Comment: please show the steps you've followed. It will be helpful to others. :)

Comment: thanks prms, all steps should be showed as comment but i was not careful to report by editing question