# Dependent validation for form mapping in play framework 2

Tags: forms, validation, playframework-2.0

Can I create mapping for form, where first validation depend from second value?

```
val orderForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "requiredDelivery" -> boolean,
      "deliveryAddress" -> text,
      "comment" -> text)
    (Order.apply)(Order.unapply)
)
```

I want to check `deliveryAddress` for `nonEmptyText` if `requiredDelivery` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val orderForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "requiredDelivery" -> boolean,
      "deliveryAddress" -> text,
      "comment" -> text)
    (Order.apply)(Order.unapply) verifying("Address is required!", fields => fields match {
      case order => (order.requiredDelivery && order.deliveryAddress!="") || !order.requiredDelivery
    })
)
```

Comment: I tried it in the first place (example from the documentation), but the problem is that the result of validatin is a common error, and no error for field. How i can mark field with `empty error`

Comment: `fields => fields match {
      case order => (order.requiredDelivery && order.deliveryAddress!="") || !order.requiredDelivery
    }` will be easier `fields => fields.requiredDelivery && !fields.deliveryAddress.isEmpty || !fields.requiredDelivery`. I also tried :-)

Comment: Found the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100698/play-framework-2-0-validate-field-in-forms-using-other-fields

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the check on deliveryAddress only, since you need requiredDelivery's value to decide whether or not throw an error, the validation needs to be a global one.

Answer (score 0):

Any form validation error that is a result from the "verifying" clause after the mapping definition goes into the "global errors". The form helpers won't display these errors, so any typical template will come up blank but not able to successfully submit the form.

The fix is to add something like this to your form template:

```
@if(userForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
  <ul>
  @for(error <- userForm.globalErrors) {
    <li>@error.message</li>
  }
  </ul>
}
```

You can learn more by looking at this page and skipping to the "Display errors in a view template" section - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-SNAPSHOT/ScalaForms